# Correct this code so that the greet function returns the expected value

Tags: php

Please help me to Correct this code so that the greet function returns the expected value.

```
 class Person {
      public $name;
      public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
      }
      public function greet($guest) {
        return 'Hello $guest, my name is $name';
      }
    }
```

Comment: i can spot the obvious problem however given what i have seen today on other questions i can't even be sure if you're using the class/functions correctly unless you show the code you use and what it outputs

Comment: I wanna show this:Expected: 'Hello $guest, my name is $name'
Actual  : 'Hello Alice, my name is Bob'

Comment: ok then we have a problem. in it's current format and if used correctly it'll do [exactly that](https://repl.it/EKO9) meaning you're not using the class/functions right and you need to show the code you use to create the class and call the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I found is with the quotes. Change [single quotes to double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/5447994). Again, you can't use variable directly. Use with `$this->name`

```
class Person {
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function greet($guest) {
        return "Hello $guest, my name is $this->name";
    }
}

$p = new Person("Bob");

echo $p->greet("Alice");
```

Will print:

```
Hello Alice, my name is Bob
```

Comment: from the [recent comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336867/correct-this-code-so-that-the-greet-function-returns-the-expected-value?noredirect=1#comment67928722_40336867) *"I wanna show this:Expected: 'Hello $guest, my name is $name' Actual : 'Hello Alice, my name is Bob'"*

Comment: It seems OP is confused with expected and actual